# Dynamically change elements color with Angular in ngRepeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to dynamically assign color to some text in angular, in an `ngRepeat` of an array of strings.

I'm having issues figuring out the 'Angular Way' of doing this. I could always setup a filter that kicks out the appropriate HSL color scheme into the element's style, but that would be very inefficient as it will have to recalculate the color each digest cycle. The `ngRepeat` array may be a few thousand items long.

If it's relevant, here is the text -> HSL conversion code:

```
function calculateColor(value){
    var saturation = [0.35, 0.5, 0.65];
    var lightness = [0.25, 0.35, 0.45];

    var hash = stringToHash(value);
    var hsl = calculateHsl(hash, lightness, saturation);
    return hsl;
}

function stringToHash(value){
    var seed = 131;
    var seed2 = 137;
    var hash = 0;
    value += 'x';

    var MAX_SAFE_INT = 9007199254740991 / seed2;
    var charArray = value.split('');

    for(var  i = 0; i < charArray.length; i++){
        if(hash >= MAX_SAFE_INT){
          hash == hash / seed2;
        }
        hash = hash * seed + charArray[i].charCodeAt(0);
    }
    return Math.abs(hash);
}

function calculateHsl(hash, lightness, saturation){
    var H,S,L;
    H = hash % 359;
    hash = hash / 360;
    S = saturation[hash % saturation.length];
    hash = hash / saturation.length;
    L = lightness[hash % lightness.length];

    return [H,S,L];
}
```

Filter:

```
chatApp.filter('toHsl', function(){
    return function(input){
      var hsl = calculateHslColor(input);
      var hslString = 'hsl('+hsl[0]+', '+hsl[1]*100+'%, '+hsl[2]*100+'%)'
      return hslString;
    }
});
```

Comment: Tell us more? Would one time binding solve the performance problem, or do you expect to update the repeat array after page load?

Comment: Do these need to update every time you load in the new list you are running the repeat on? what are your constraints and such?

Comment: @Dan Thanks for the reply. One time binding would actually work, the text will not change after it's in the array. Ajmaj It only needs to be set once per element

Comment: then filter (with your logics) + 1 way bind

Comment: @ajmajmajma I'm not familiar with one-way binding a filter, but I'll look into it to find out what it is.

Comment: You just filter as normal and bind your components 1 way with {{::oneWayBind}}, or wherever you are binding the colors, just use the `::`

Comment: @ajmajmajma That was definitely what I needed, answer if you want and I'll accept it. I've added a code snipped with the filter that you can use in your answer. Otherwise I'll answer the question later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the filter just like you were planning to, but you can save on performance by using the 1-way binding angular has to only evaluate each item once.

So you have your filter and then your ng-repeat would look something like this, depending on how exactly you are binding those colors :

```
<div ng-repeat="item in colorList">
     <div>{{::('item'| toHsl)}}</div>
```

Or

```
<div ng-repeat="item in colorList | filter:toHsl"> 
     <div> {{::item}}</div>
```

you can 1 way bind to attributes just the same with 1-way binding, just make sure you use the `::`.